# TypeScript React img src prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a component that needs to pass a `src` prop to an `img` tag. My `Prop` type is:

```
type Props = {
    src: React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>.src?: string | undefined;
};
```

but I get `';' expected.` at `t>.src`. I don't know why I get an error because I literally copied/pasted the src prop type from hovering over `src` in `<img src="" />`. How do I correctly specify the `src` prop in my `Prop` type?

Comment: src is just `string | undefined`. remove averything before. you have copy/past the src field definition of the type and its types..

Comment: What is the `?` doing there? That is probably what the linter/compiler is complaining about.

Comment: What about imported image files for `src`? Do those count as strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
type Props = {
     src?: string | undefined;
};
```